# Can't connect my raspberry-pi to internet via Ethernet connection + ICS connection failed

Tags: raspberry-pi, windows-7, ethernet

I have a raspberry pi 3 connected to my PC (Windows 7) via ethernet using DHCP server and VNC viewer and it works perfectly.
The pc is connected to a WIFI.
I want to access to internet from my raspberry pi, I tried the ICS sharing but it didn't work:

- I shared the wifi connection:[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23wBV.png)
- changed the ip address: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlMOB.png)
- after sharing the wifi connection, I am unable to access internet from both the pc and rasp even though they are in the same ip address.
  [On PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujhPb.png),[On the Rasp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSy8S.png)

Can you please help me to find a solution?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a network bridge.
Select the two networks, right click and select bridge connections.
I'd use static IP address on your PI and your PC's ethernet

[image: Network bridge in Windows 7]